# Set default background with possibility to change it (Swift)

Tags: ios, swift

I would like to set a default background in viewDidLoad as that:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let bkgrnd1 = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
    bkgrnd1.image = UIImage(named: "bkgrnd1.png")
    bkgrnd1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
    self.view.insertSubview(bkgrnd1, at: 0)
}
```

After that, I would like to have 2 more individual UIButton that go to replace and/or deactivate the default "bkgrnd1" with another "bkgrnd2.png".

Comment: It's no longer common practice to abbreviate words like that (`bkgrnd`), we have big screens now, and `backgroundView` would look much cleaner and provide more information. Ideally your variable and type names should be as explicit as possible while being concise.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to make `bkgrnd1` an instance variable to access it inside all functions of the vc as it currently a local var

```
var bkgrnd1 : UIImageView!

  override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

      bkgrnd1 = UIImageView(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)
      bkgrnd1.image = UIImage(named: "bkgrnd1.png")
      bkgrnd1.contentMode = UIView.ContentMode.scaleAspectFill
      self.view.insertSubview(bkgrnd1, at: 0)
}
```

Then do

```
bkgrnd1.image = UIImage(named: "bkgrnd2.png")
```

any where , if you want to hide set

```
bkgrnd1.isHiddden = true
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, i'm still wondering how to apply those change to all my view, as it apply only to the first view (all my view are ViewController), do you know hot to apply to every view?